# Binding DropDownList using code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The data binding works only when the page loads first time but it does not work otherwise. Somewhere in my page, i update and insert some new "Names" and i would like to show the newly added Names to be shown in the dropdownlist.  But if i reload the page then the newly added Name will appear in the dropdownlist.  How can i refresh the items in the dropdown? i thought my code should work.  Pls help.  thanks

```
 private void RefreshDropDown()
    {
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [Main] order by Name asc");

        cmd1.Connection = con2;
        con2.Open();
        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Name";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        con2.Close();

}
```

Comment: Dont you want to show newly added items in dropdown?  You say that when u reload page then names appear in list

Comment: DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

Comment: What event in the page life cycle are you calling this?

Comment: Please post all of your code, markup and code-behind.

Comment: That means you just bind the items in your page load when it is not a postback, so you should change it to do it always. Anyways post your code so we can write your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have some kind of button to do insert of new names.
So on click of this button add call for RefreshDropDown() after you done inserting /updating your new names.
That should do the trick.